# Why is there a tag "unknown performer"?

Tags: support, tags

There appears to be a tag [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer). Considering that all identification questions are tagged "identify-(something)", can someone replace this with [identify-this-band](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-band), please?

On a related note, isn't [identify-this-band](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-band) limiting? Wouldn't [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist) be better?

Comment: Related questions about the [tag:unknown-composer] tag: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/3955 and https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/488/3955

Answer (score 1):

I was asking myself the same question when I submitted a tag info about [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer). I agree identifying tags should have a common syntax, [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist)(that already exists) is better as it suits for singers, musicians, composers, DJs, etc...

[unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer) may be used for questions about actually unknown performer (or unknown composers) like traditional songs, old famous tunes where the original performer or composer is really unknown.