# The [unknown-composer] tag is used for many purposes, so do we need an [identify-this-composer] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We currently do not have a tag called [identify-this-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-composer), but I feel there is a decent case for adding it.

Currently, the [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer) tag seems to be used for the purpose of identifying a composer: out of the 10 questions tagged [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer),

- 4 questions are about identifying the composer:

  - <s>[Voegeli's "All things Considered" Theme Song and It's Hollywood Connection](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/8070/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Who writes the original music for Mozart in the Jungle](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4554/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Who composed the tracks "Flower Girl" and "受け継がれし技" from the Shenmue OST?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/388/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Of all authors who may have composed "Adeste Fideles", is there one who is most likely to have done it?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4998/3955)</s>

*(The above questions have all been retagged as [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist).)*

- 5 questions are about identifying a song in which the composer is unknown:

  - <s>[Identify classical song frequently used as songtrack for "posh" settings](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7118/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Unknown avant-garde piano song performed by Kyari Leen Alcantara](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6305/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Instrumental: lead guitar, orchestral accompaniment](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5650/3955)</s>
  - <s>[Classical song, flute and string orchestra, instrumental](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3164/3955)</s>
  - <s>https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7257/3955</s>

*(The first four questions in the above list are retagged as [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song), and the fifth question has been deleted.)*

- 1 question is about an unknown composer:

  - [Does Gautam Malhotra (a composer) really exist?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4761/3955)

---

It seems incorrect to me to add the tag (unknown-composer) to a question tagged (identify-this-song), because if the composer is unknown, then asking to identify the song implicitly asks to identify the composer as well. If anything, such questions should be tagged (identify-this-composer) instead of (unknown-composer), or should only have the (identify-this-song) tag.

So, I feel that 9 out of the 10 questions tagged (unknown-composer) should really be tagged (identify-this-composer). Shall we create such a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that this question had two separate issues under discussion: (1) how to use the (unknown-composer) tag correctly, and (2) whether we need an (identify-this-composer) tag.

Based on the previous answers, most of the example questions cited in the OP have been retagged, based on the following understanding (taken from [@Bebs' answer](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/491/3955)):

> Using (unknown-composer) to identify a song is most of the time mis-tagging since like (unknown-performer), the tag should be used for **a question about an actually unknown composer**, or performer (unknown by the world, like in very old recordings, traditional songs, anonymous) **not for the questions where the composer is unknown by OP**.

*(emphasis mine)*

This completely answers (1), so I'll go ahead and mark this question as answered.

A more focussed question regarding the creation of an (identify-this-composer) tag can be asked separately if anyone is interested.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion for using the [tag:unknown-composer] tag, and I think that [tag:identify-this-composer] is also needed.

Comment: @PiedPiper thank you for responding! I commented this under Chris Sunami’s answer as well: do you also think that it makes sense to rename (identify-this-artist) to (identify-this-performer), assuming the composer tag gets created?

Comment: Yes, I agree (identify-this-performer) makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Bebs that `unknown-performer` and `unknown-composer` are being misused.  However, I think Brahadeesh is correct that the `unknown-composer` questions should be re-tagged as `identify-this-composer`.

I think Bebs may be referencing his answer largely to the contemporary world of music, which is performer-focused, where many people sing their own songs, and where it's relatively rare to be able to identify the performer, but not the songwriter.  However, in the world of classical music, which is composer-focused, **it's quite possible to know the performer but not the composer, or vice versa, and they are almost never the same person**.

On a more personal note, I'm not opposed to granular tags, if they are useful.

Comment: Sure, I have edited

Comment: It just occurred to me, since you support the creation of an (identify-this-composer) tag, would you feel that changing (identify-this-artist) to (identify-this-performer) makes more sense, assuming the composer tag gets created? This is a kind of converse to [this question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/488/3955).

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need of "identify-this-composer" tag since we already have [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist). By artist, it could mean singer, musician, dancer, back-up extra, composer, etc. We shouldn't have too much of this tags or it would be too granular.
2. Using [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer) to identify a song is most of the time mis-tagging since like [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer), the tag should be used for a question about an actually unknown composer, or performer (unknown by the world, like in very old recordings, traditional songs, anonymous) not for the questions where the composer is unknown by OP.