# Should we merge the tags [unknown-performer] and [unknown-composer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We currently have the two tags [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer) and [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer). However, we use the single tag [identify-this-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist) for questions asking to identify all artists: singer, musician, dancer, back-up extra, composer, etc. [as mentioned by @Bebs in this answer](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/491/3955).

So, to maintain the same level of tagging (that is, neither finer nor coarser), I propose that we merge the tags [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer) and [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer) into a single tag called [unknown-artist](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-artist).

Does this reasoning seem agreeable? Here are the current stats on the two tags:

- 11 questions tagged solely [unknown-performer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer), 2 unanswered.
- 7 questions tagged solely [unknown-composer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer), 2 unanswered.
- 1 question tagged with both, 0 unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree.  The performer may not be the composer.  In the case of classical music, the performer is almost certainly not the composer.  It is quite possible to know one and not the other.